# user choicen variable removed off list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an array and I want to remove or add an item that the user chooses like `my_list.remove(input("which item do you remove")`. How would I do this properly?

I would expect the code I have written to remove the item the user chooses(if it is on the list) out of the list just like a normal remove command except with user input

Am I missing something obvious? I started python a few days ago and I am not very good at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python (2 or 3) script to achieve this:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from builtins import input
mylist = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple']
mylist.pop(mylist.index(input('Which element do you want to remove from the list?')))
print(mylist)
```

Usage:

```
$python foo.py
Which element do you want to remove from the list?apple
['banana', 'pineapple']
$ python3 foo.py
Which element do you want to remove from the list?pineapple
['apple', 'banana']
```

Should you try to remove something not in the list, the error is actually pretty spot on:

```
Which element do you want to remove from the list?peach
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    mylist.pop(mylist.index(input('Which element do you want to remove from the list?')))
ValueError: 'peach' is not in list
```

Comment: Better to use `remove` than `pop`/`index`

Answer (score 1):

**For an instance, you have list ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] and you want to remove any value between of this list**

```
li = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
remove_value = input("Which item do you want to remove: ")
li.remove(remove_value)
print(li)
```

And output will be:

```
>>> Which item do you want to remove: i # this is the value you want to remove
>>> ['a', 'e', 'o', 'u']
```

For more details: [More on Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple python demo below. you can remove or add item like you want.

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

hobbies_list = ['cooking', 'basketball', 'walking', 'reading']


def remove_hobby():
    target = input("Which item do you want to remove: ").lower()

    if target in hobbies_list:
        hobbies_list.remove(target)
    else:
        print("This item {} does not exist".format(target))


def add_hobby():
    target = input("Which item do you want to add: ").lower()
    if target in hobbies_list:
        print("This item {} does not exist".format(target))
    else:
        hobbies_list.append(target)
        print("This item {} add success ".format(target))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("current hobbies:{}".format(','.join(hobbies_list)))
    remove_hobby()
    print("current hobbies:{}".format(','.join(hobbies_list)))
    add_hobby()
    print("current hobbies:{}".format(','.join(hobbies_list)))
```